# Vim indent folding dependencies

Tags: vim, indentation, folding

I'm trying to enable vim indent folding.
From what I can see online, setting `:set fdm=indent`should just work. For me, it doesn't do anything. I can fold manually, but I'm quite strict about indenting code, so indent-folding is ideal. I use spaces to indent (two spaces per level)

My ~/.vimrc looks like this:

```
set foldmethod=indent
```

and is definitely being loaded (according to `:scriptnames`)

Is vim folding in some way dependent on the file type? I'm writing C CUDA, so the extension is .cu.
Do I have to install some sort of plugin for indent folding? I know it's a broad question, but this seems like basic functionality and I have no idea why it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`set nofoldenable` turns off folding, it should be `set foldenable` to enable it

Also `set foldlevel=2` sets how many levels **of the identified folds** should be visible. If you want to specify the depth of indent to use for folding, the setting to use is `shiftwidth` (e.g., `set shiftwidth=2`)

Comment: Ah, good spot on the `set nofoldenable`, but i removed that line from .vimrc and still nothing. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, by "visible" do you mean "open"? as in, if I have `set foldlevel=2` then the 1st 2 layers of indentation will *not* be folded?
Either way, I've played with this parameter and still cant get any indent folding to happen.

Comment: What is your `shiftwidth` set to?

Comment: Ah! `set shiftwidth=2` now works! I must've still had `set nofoldenable` the 1st time I tried it. Solved. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Another register I found that needs to be looked at if the fold behavior is "ignoring" what is clearly indented: make sure `foldminlines` is set to 1 to generate all the folds you might expect.

This, in addition to the `shiftwidth` setting to something like 2, or even 1 to generate a new fold level with every single space difference.

- E